# How to combine longtable and multiple bullet points per cell?

Tags: longtable, bullets, excel2latex

I have a long table (30 rows), currently 4 columns, but this might increase given the available page width.

When I followed the instructions for a long table (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/a-longtable-example/xxwzfxkxxjmc), it all worked. Likewise, when I tried the instructions for bulleted items (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325585/bullet-list-inside-a-table-cell), it also worked (for me, it just needed only \documentclass{article} at the very top)

Now I tried to combine the two but it just looks and is wrong: There are no bullets and the table structure has disappeared. It all appears to start when I add hline after \endlastfoot.

Essentially, I am looking for a way, to have a long table (probably spanning 2-3pages; the table is currently roughly 8 pages in Word), where the second, third, and fourth columns all have multiple bullet points (not always the same amount of bullet points) per row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Fourth column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Fourth column}}  \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

\hline
  One &
  \begin{itemize} 
            \item Remote delivery 
            \item Immersive experiences 
   \end{itemize}  

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla\\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would be most grateful for any help or advice!

Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. I also tried excel2latex, but my work computer neither lets the add-in run in protected view, nor does it allow access to the App store. At home, I have a macbook, which does not seem to work with excel2latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use the `longtable` package, I offer you an alternative with the `tabularray` package. Lots of examples on this site.

For the `itemize` environment, I use the package `enumitem` to create a new list (CHAPTER 5. USE SOME LIBRARIES in tabularray documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}% <-- for the environment itemize

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{
          nosep,     % <-- new list setup
          leftmargin = *,
          label = $\bullet$,
                    }

\begin{document}
% \begingroup
% \small
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {A sample long table.},
  label = {tab:long},
                ]{
  hlines,vlines,
  % colspec = { *{4}{X} },             
  colspec = {X Q[l, wd=5cm] *{2}{X[1.5]}},
  row {1} = {font=\bfseries,halign=c,valign=m},
  rowhead = 1,
  measure = vbox,% <-- for the itemize
                }
Fist column&Second column&Third column&Fourth column\\
One &
\begin{tabitemize} 
          \item Remote delivery 
          \item Immersive experiences 
\end{tabitemize}\\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & Blabla\\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtblr}
% \endgroup


\end{document}
```

[image]